# WCF and Windows Server Service Bus Endpoints

Tags: wcf, appfabric, servicebus

I need to develop a Windows Server Service Bus topic subscriber (yes, Windows Server and not Azure), and in order to abstract away from the reading, start worker thread, ..., cycle and to take advantage of AppFabric management capabilities, i had the following idea:

- Develop a WCF service
- Define a Windows Server Service Bus endpoint

And the questions are:

1. A publisher must use the Service Contract  to send messages to the topic?
2. What should the configuration file look like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help future related problems here is the required configuration

**Extensions required both in publisher and subscriber configuration**:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </behaviorExtensions>

  <bindingExtensions>
    <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
```

**Note**: The Microsoft.ServiceBus assembly is required both in the publisher as well in the subscriber. The package is available in [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceBus.v1_0).

**Subscriber side configuration**:

```
<bindings>
  <netMessagingBinding>
    <binding name="messagingBinding" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" sessionIdleTimeout="00:01:00" prefetchCount="-1">
      <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:01" />
    </binding>
  </netMessagingBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="securityBehavior">
      <messageInterceptorBehavior/>
      <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        <tokenProvider>
          <windowsAuthentication>
            <stsUris>
              <stsUri value="https://[SERVER]:9355/[NAMESPACE]" />
            </stsUris>
          </windowsAuthentication>
        </tokenProvider>
      </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
</behavior>

<endpoint listenUri="sb://[SERVER]/[NAMESPACE]/[TOPIC]/Subscriptions/[SUBSCRIPTIONNAME]"
              address="sb://[SERVER]/[NAMESPACE]/[TOPIC]"
              behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" binding="netMessagingBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding" name="InsuranceService"
              contract="[WCF_CONTRACT_NAME]" />
```

**Publisher configuration**:

```
<bindings>
  <netMessagingBinding>
    <binding name="InsuranceService" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" prefetchCount="-1"
      sessionIdleTimeout="00:01:00">
      <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:01" />
    </binding>
  </netMessagingBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="securityBehavior">
      <messageInterceptorBehavior/>
      <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        <tokenProvider>
          <windowsAuthentication>
            <stsUris>
              <stsUri value="https://[SERVER]:9355/[NAMESPACE]" />
            </stsUris>
          </windowsAuthentication>
        </tokenProvider>
      </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
  <endpoint address="sb://[SERVER]/[NAMESPACE]/[TOPIC]"
    behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" binding="netMessagingBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="InsuranceService" contract="PushVoucherService.ISubscriber"
    name="InsuranceService" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic mechanics of how to connect WCF and Service Bus are the same between the Azure and the Server versions. [You can use this post as a good starting point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/10/09/using-service-bus-topics-and-subscriptions-with-wcf.aspx):

The main difference between the two is going to be with the endpoint addresses, and how to deal with authentication (since there's no ACS in the server). [This post has some useful information on it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj218331%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Now, to answer your questions specifically:

- A publisher could technically push directly to the service bus queues, but it's better if you use a contract.  The problem here is not how to push, but how to build the message in a way that the service can understand it. Having a WCF contract will let you abstract the serialization / deserialization away.
- For the configuration, the typical scenario would be to have a WCF service that uses [netMessagingBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.netmessagingbinding.aspx). The first post I mentioned has information on the configuration. Just make sure to update the auth and endpoint address pieces to match service bus server's.

Comment: Thanks Ramiro. Using netMessageBinding i am able to publish messages to the topic and apparently receiving messages from a subscription. But, even if the messages are consumed from the subscription they don't seem to be processed by the service itself. I built a simple interceptor implementation of IDispatchMessageInspector, but it doesn't get call if i am using a SB endpoint. It is called if i'm using a Http endpoint.

Comment: Where are you hosting your webservice? If you're using IIS, you need to first activate the service (in IIS's model, a WCF doesn't become active until a request comes). The documentation on how to setup up IIS to work with SB is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh966775.aspx

Comment: It seems that the problem was due to an invalid endpoint configuration. The address attribute must contain the topic URI while the listenURI points to the subscription URI. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi folks -- I work on the Service Bus documentation team, and we realized that the link in this post titled [**This post has some useful information on it**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj218331%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) no longer exists. I would recommend that you check out this topic instead: [**Getting Started with Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282152.aspx), which contains similar (but even more useful!) information.

Thanks and please do keep the feedback coming! We are listening...